# Other numbers with property $1 + 2 + \cdots + 2^{n-1} = 2^n - 1 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is well known that $$1 + 2 + \cdots + 2^{n-1} = 2^n - 1 $$

This means that $2^n$ is equal to one more than the sum of all its proper divisors.

It turns out the only integers with this property are of the form $2^n$ ($n \ge 0$), but I have no idea how to prove this. Any hints?

Comment: It seems to be an open problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_perfect_number

Comment: Consider the geometric series for other $p^n$ possibly? It would be one idea though composite numbers could be tricky to do.

Comment: I don't think OP means other numbers $p$, but rather $N$ so that $\sigma(N)=2N-1$. @JBKing

Comment: Don't give up guys, it could be you

Comment: Why has this been voted to close? My question is perfectly clear. And how exactly is my question not about mathematics?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  for $p$ prime.  $p \ne 2$, $1 + p + ... + p^{n} = \frac {p^{n+1} - 1}{p - 1} > p^n$.

So if $p^n$ is a factor the sum of factors will include summands $1, p, p^2.... p^n$ which when multiplied and distributed by other prime power factors will will be greater than $p^{n+1}*\text {sum of factors of m divided by p to the n}$

So if $m = \prod p_i^{k_i}$, with distribution and induction, sum of all factors > $\prod p_i^{k_i + 1}$ so, 1 more than sum of proper fractions $> \prod p_i^{k_i + 1} - m + 1 = \prod p_i^{k_i + 1} - \prod p_i^{k_i} + 1> \prod p_i^{k_i} = m$.

Okay, it needs to be polished and cases of m = p or multiple of single powers of primes need to be ironed out.  But in general that's the gyst.

======

Okay, more formally.

Let f(m) = sum of all factors (including m) of integer m.

Our property m = 1 + sum of proper factors $\iff$ f(m) = 2m - 1.

If $m = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ ($p_i$ prime). $f(p_i^{k_i}) = 1 + p_i + ... + p_i^{k_i} = \frac{p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1}{p_i - 1}$.  So $f(m) = \frac{p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1}{p_i - 1}*f(m/p_i^{k_i}) = \prod \frac{p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1}{p_i - 1} $

For all $p_i > 2$, $\frac{p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1}{p_i - 1} > p^{k_i}+1 $.

So if $f(m = 2^n\prod p_i^{k_i}; p_i \text { odd}) = (2^{n+1} - 1)\prod \frac{p_i^{k_i + 1} - 1}{p_i - 1} > (2^{n+1} - 1)\prod (p_i^{k_i}+1)> 2m -1$ If any $p_i \ne 1$ and $n > 1$ or $n = 0$ but there are at least two $p_i$.

If, on the other hand, $m = p;p > 3$ then $ f(m) = 1 + p \ne 2p - 1$

So $m = 2^n$ are the only integers with this property.

Comment: How $ \frac {p^n - 1}{p - 1} > p^n$?

Comment: @MahbubAlam It isn't true for any $p$ or $n$.

Comment: Yeah. I asked to change the answer actually.

Comment: Yeah yeah I know

Comment: Argh.  First line is not a good place for a typo.  The OP refered to sum to 2^(n - 1) = 2^n - 1 but I thought sum to p^n = p^(n+1) -1/p-1 would be more useful indexing that sum to p^(n-1) = p^n - 1/p-1 but I guess I missed an index

Comment: Actually I changed my mind which index to use (to n-1 => n or to n => n+1) and seem to have changed my mind mid sentence.